# Unknown device error installing Lexmark printer in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, lexmark-printer

I have been using Lexmark X3650 All-In-One on my Windows Vista Desktop PC for a year without problem. Yesterday, I was prompted to plug in the USB from the printer and after that I got errors: "The USB device has malfunctioned." ,"The unknown device has been installed unsuccessfully.". Then, the printer just stoped responding. I have uninstalled the driver from Device Manager and software (using Lexmark's clean utility), rebooted, reinstalled, same thing, tried different ports/cable. Vista displays these two errors stated above immediately upon plug in.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like the USB interface on your printer has given up the magic smoke that makes it work.

Assuming that other USB devices work in these ports then your computer should be fine.  The last thing you could try is to see if the printer will work on another computer, if you get the same error then I'm am afraid that chances are your printer has died.

If, on the other hand, the printer works fine then there is potentially some kind of driver corruption that will need to be looked in to.